# how to upload folder to server in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I think the Folder upload is supported java applet.
But  how can i use java applets in Asp.net c#
Please tell me about this, without the Flash and silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Oracles website on [Java Applets, ASP.net - Can You Play Together?](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/appletAspIntegration/)

> Is your web application platform based
>   on ASP.net technology? Would you like
>   to leverage the Java platform's
>   ubiquity to provide a rich user
>   experience when users visit your web
>   site? You can develop secure rich
>   Internet applications (RIAs - applets
>   and Java Web Start applications) by
>   using the Java or the JavaFX language.
>   Java client technology integrates
>   seamlessly with ASP.net technology. In
>   this article, we will explore various
>   mechanisms by which Java applets can
>   interact with ASP.net web pages.

Comment: i am reading this tutorial i will make the sample application by uisng this.

Comment: perfect! if you like the answer you should makr it as accepted by pressing the "Accept answer" icon to the left of my answer.